# How to fix Fortify Path Manipulation ( Input Validation and Representation , Data Flow ) vulnerability

Tags: java, file, path, fortify

I am getting fortify path manipulation vulnerability for creating a file with new keyword

I have tried to sanitize the path before passing it to File object, but the problem persists.
Tried this link also:
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO00-J.+Do+not+operate+on+files+in+shared+directories

```
public static String sanitizePath(String sUnsanitized) throws URISyntaxException, EncodingException {

   String sSanitized = SAPI.encoder().canonicalize(sUnsanitized);
   return sSanitized;

}


//// the main method code snippet /////

String sSanitizedPath = Utils.sanitizePath(file.getOriginalFilename());

-- fortify scan detects problem here ..in below line --

File filePath = new File(AppInitializer.UPLOAD_LOCATION, sSanitizedPath);

String canonicalPath = filePath.getCanonicalPath();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(canonicalPath);
```

After the santizePath , I thought the scan will be not pick ,vulnerabilit but , it did.

Comment: I tried new File(path.normalize().toString()) but this also does not work .Infact it raised 1 more flag for vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

This "sUnsanitized" variable comes from user input? Maybe this is your real problem.

Never trust in user input its a number one rule to develpment.

Comment: The file name comes from user input , there is no other way but process the the input .

Comment: Do you really need to maintain the original filename? If this is true, ok. You just need to care about the filename itself. I guy can send to  you a .cmd, .bat, .exe somethig like that. If you take care about this issue, can you mark this as false positive.